# Issue connecting to MongoDB Atlas when using Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I'm building a simple node.js / express app where I us MongoDB Atlas for data storage. When I locally run the app using `node index.js` everything works as expected. I can connect to MongoDB Atlas and read/write data.

Now I want this app to run inside a Docker container. The image is build without issues using `docker build . -t IMAGENAME --network=host` (had to add --network=host as otherwise some dependencies can not be loaded). When I start the container using `docker run -p 4000:3000 -d IMAGENAME:latest` the app starts as expected.

However, I can not connect to MongoDB Atlas and receive the following error:

```
Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.dbcluster0.kux1t.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.dbcluster0.kux1t.mongodb.net'
}
```

Any idea why I'm able to connect to Atlas without running Docker but not when running the image in a container?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /backend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

This is the connection string I'm using (also tried format for node 2.2.12):

```
MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://username:password@dbcluster0.kux1t.mongodb.net/database1?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was related to my host network configuration. Running docker with the `--network host` argument during build and run solved the issue